# Xaml WebView: Get/Set content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm making use of the following Win 8.1 Xaml control:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.WebView

The problem is, that I want to get hold of the content once it has loaded and then make some alterations to the content. More specifically, I want to remove all YouTube embedded content. Is there anyway I can do this?

Your help and feedback is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll be able to do this via javascript.

Found this code on [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/03/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview-*2d00*-an-update-for-windows-8.1.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/03/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview-_2d00_-an-update-for-windows-8.1.aspx)

```
await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.write('Hello World!')" });
```

Should be able to replace `document.write('Hello World')` with the javascript that will remove the youtube videos.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but if you load web content by making use of the Navigate method, how will you inject your own custom JavaScript into the existing page? Thanks